# How can I format the names of enum-constants from ZodiacInfo inside another enum?

Tags: java, string, class, enums

My program has an enum which contains a constructor.

```
public enum ZodiacType {
    ARI(ZodiacInfo.Aries, "March 21", "April 19"),
    TAU(ZodiacInfo.Taurus, "April 20", "May 20"),
    GEM(ZodiacInfo.Gemini, "May 21", "June 20"),
    CAN(ZodiacInfo.Cancer, "June 21", "July 22"),
    LEO(ZodiacInfo.Leo, "July 23", "August 22"),
    VIR(ZodiacInfo.Virgo, "August 23", "September 22"),
    LIB(ZodiacInfo.Libra, "September 23", "October 22"),
    SCO(ZodiacInfo.Scorpio, "October 23", "November 21"),
    SAG(ZodiacInfo.Sagittarius, "November 22", "December 21"),
    CAP(ZodiacInfo.Capricorn, "December 22", "January 19"),
    AQU(ZodiacInfo.Aquarius, "January 20", "February 18"),
    PIS(ZodiacInfo.Pisces, "February 19", "March 20");

    private final ZodiacInfo description;
    private final String startDate;
    private final String toDate;

    ZodiacType(ZodiacInfo description, String startDate, String toDate) {
        this.description = description;
        this.startDate = startDate;
        this.toDate = toDate;
    }
}
```

Here is my output currently that I made thanks to the past solutions.

Here is an example of a Set:

```
A = {LEO, CAN, VIR, GEM, SAG, TAU, CAP}
// All elements in set are distinct and random number
```

My custom class `Set`:

```
public class Set {
    private ArrayList<ZodiacType> s;

    public Set() {
        s = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("A = {%s}",
            s.toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", ""));
    }
}
```

Here is the method that I developed.

```
public String getStringZodiacInfoFormat() {
    // not correct to put arrayList
    ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
    for (ZodiacType zodiacType: s) {
        strings.add(zodiacType.name());
    }
    return String.format("A = {%s}",
            strings.toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", ""))
}
```

The question is I can't convert it and the result is:

```
Notation in enum format
A = {GEM, LIB, CAN, PIS, SCO, ARI, VIR}
......................................................
```

Instead of this:

```
Notation in enum format
A = {Gemini, Libra, Cancer, Pisces, Scorpio, Aries, Virgo}
......................................................
```

I can learn new things from any given solutions. Thank you

Comment: do you mean the code should use the `description` instead of `zodiacType.name()`?

Comment: Yes, introduce/override: `ZodiacType#toString()`, which (does:)`return description.name();`

Comment: But if I introduce a new toString in enum, it might messed up my first output `Here is an example of set
    A = {LEO, CAN, VIR, GEM, SAG, TAU, CAP}
    All elements in set are distinct and random number`

Comment: user16320675, yes I want to directly use `description` instead of `zodiacType.name()` but I can't in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the required string representation by using [`StringJoiner`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/StringJoiner.html).

One of its constructors allows specifying the *delimiter*, as well as the *prefix* and the *suffix* which would be used in the joined string.

Method [`StringJoiner.add()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/StringJoiner.html#add(java.lang.CharSequence)) is used to add a new string to `StringJoiner`. And method [`StringJoiner.toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/StringJoiner.html#toString()) generates the resulting string.

Assuming that members `ZodiacInfo` have converntional **upper-case** names (ARIES, VIRGO, etc.), you can use the following code to join capitalized descriptions together:

```
public String getStringZodiacInfoFormat() {
    
    StringJoiner strings = new StringJoiner(", ", "{", "}");
    
    for (ZodiacType zodiacType: s) {
        
        String type = zodiacType.description().name();
        strings.add(type.charAt(0) + type.substring(1).toLowerCase());
    }
    return strings.toString();
}
```

**Note:** the cleaner approach would be to place the logic for creating capitalized `ZodiacInfo` name into the `toString()` implementation of the `ZodiacType` enum, or if you want to display dates in the `toString()` as well, then introduce a separate method, let's say `getZodiacName()`.

That's how such method might look like:

```
public enum ZodiacType {
    // enum-members, etc.
    
    public String getZodiacName() {
        String type = description.name();
        return type.charAt(0) + type.substring(1).toLowerCase();
    }
}
```

---

Judging by your code, the names of `ZodiacInfo` members are not aligned with the [Java naming convention](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html) (i.e. `ZodiacInfo.Aries` instead of recommended `ZodiacInfo.ARIES`).

If for some reason you want to keep them like that (`Aries`, `Virgo`), then you don't need the logic for capitalizing the name.

And the method `getStringZodiacInfoFormat()` can be written like this:

```
public String getStringZodiacInfoFormat() {
    
    StringJoiner strings = new StringJoiner(", ", "{", "}");
    
    for (ZodiacType zodiacType: s) {
        
        strings.add(zodiacType.description().name());
    }
    return strings.toString();
}
```

Comment: This is the format that I want: `Notation in enum format
A = {Gemini, Libra, Cancer, Pisces, Scorpio, Aries, Virgo}
......................................................` but the thing I should take it from the constructor in enum which is the ZodiacInfo description attribute.

Comment: @MingLiang You want to use `description` instead of `Enum.name()`, is that correct? If yes, can you provide your `ZodiacInfo` enum in the question?

Comment: okie I already provide my `ZodiacInfo` in my question, thanks for giving the solution.

Comment: @MingLiang But I still don't see the code of the in your question `ZodiacInfo`. Note, that enum names like `ZodiacInfo.Aries` are unconventional. The name that compliant with the [Java naming convention](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html) would be `ZodiacInfo.ARIES`

Comment: @MingLiang If for some reason you don't want the name to adhere to the convention and keep it like `Aries`, `Virgo`, then you don't need the logic for capitalizing the name. In the code above, you can directly use the name of a `ZodiacInfo` constant `strings.add(zodiacType.description().name());`